# Regex pattern for replacing insignificant zeros after decimal in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which replaces all zeros `0` in a string which is after a dot `.` and does not have any digit `0-9` after it. For example

`$2,305.690` ---> `$2,305.69`, `20,345.690000 %` ---> `20,345.69 %`, `345.609##` ---> `345.609##`, `23.000` --> `23`, `0.00` --> `0`

I tried this `(/(?<=\..*)0(?=.*[^0-9].*)/g, '')` but it throws an exception, may be because JavaScript does not support Lookbehinds.

Please suggest a JS regex solution.

Comment: "And does not have any digit `0-9`" - didn't you mean `1-9`?

Comment: @Asunez yea.. I guess you are correct.. but does that make any difference in my case of requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\.(\d*?)0+(\D*)$
```

And replace with `.$1$2` if the group 1 length is more than 0 or with `$1$2` otherwise. It can be done in the callback function (see below).

The regex matches:

- `\.` - a decimal separator (literal `.`)
- `(\d*?)` - 0 or more digits (captured group 1 - all digits after the separator up to trailing zeros), as few as possible
- `0+` - 1 or more zeros...
- `(\D*)` - that are followed by 0 or more non-digits (captured group 2)...
- `$` - right before the end of string (or line in multiline mode)

```js
var re = /\.(\d*?)0+(\D*)$/gm; 
var str = '$2,305.690\n ---> $2,305.69, \n20,345.690 %\n ---> 20,345.69 %, \n345.609##\n ---> 345.609##\n$2,305.000000\n --> $2,305\n0.000\n ---> 0';
var result = str.replace(re, function(m, grp1, grp2) {
    return (grp1.length > 0 ? "." : "") + grp1 + grp2;
  });
document.write(result.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

Comment: Please check out the update. I hope it will work for all cases now.

Comment: great update.. It is more generic now.. but could you also take care of the case `0.000` --> `0`     Is it even possible?

Comment: @DopedDude: I have just checked and it works as you have requested: `0.000` becomes `0`.

Comment: I guess it contains the `.` at end in the output... which is not required in case there are no digits after the decimal. Please refer https://regex101.com/r/lE6bK1/2

Comment: Please see my updated snippet. I fixed 2 things at once with this callback function: 1) cases when trailing zeros are the only decimal digits, and 2) if the period remains the only one left, it is not put back into the resulting string. Input contains `0.000`, result is `0`. The regex101 is only a regex demo, but not the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(\.[0-9]+)0+(\D+)
```

This'll capture decimal values and the rest of the characters including `0` just simply replace using `$1$2` and all done

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/42)

Comment: Please add `.` to the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex.

```
(\.\d*?[1-9]*)(0+)(\s*%?)$
```

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
var number = '$2,305.69000';
number = number.replace(/(\.\d*?[1-9]*)(0+)(\s*%?)$/,'$1$3');
alert(number);   //shows $2,305.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea may be but will do the work

```
var num = '200.00900';
if (num.match(/[.]\d+/)) {//~num.indexOf('.') will fail when num will be '200.'
  num = num.replace(/0+\b/g, '');
}
console.log(num);
```